# How to pass variable to a make command?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with :

```
zvals: resize
    zMin=$$(gdalinfo -mm ./crop_xl.tmp.tif | sed -ne 's/.*Computed Min\/Max=//p'| tr -d ' ' | cut -d "," -f 1 | cut -d . -f 1);\
    zMax=$$(gdalinfo -mm ./crop_xl.tmp.tif | sed -ne 's/.*Computed Min\/Max=//p'| tr -d ' ' | cut -d "," -f 2 | cut -d . -f 1);\
    echo Altidutes range: $$zMin $$zMax
    python ../script/slice.py $$zMin $$zMax $(SLICES) > ./slices.tmp.txt
```

Last line fails because `$$zMin` and `$$zMax` in `python ../script/slice.py $$zMin $$zMax $(SLICES) > ./slices.tmp.txt` are empty and fail to provide any numbers to the python command.

Meanwhile, the exact same  `$$zMin` and `$$zMax` in `echo Altidutes range: $$zMin $$zMax` properly prints `Altidutes range: -`

#### Hack

My "hack" is to inline it ALL via systematic `;\` at the end of each lines :

```
zvals: resize
    zMin=$$(gdalinfo -mm ./crop_xl.tmp.tif | sed -ne 's/.*Computed Min\/Max=//p'| tr -d ' ' | cut -d "," -f 1 | cut -d . -f 1);\
    zMax=$$(gdalinfo -mm ./crop_xl.tmp.tif | sed -ne 's/.*Computed Min\/Max=//p'| tr -d ' ' | cut -d "," -f 2 | cut -d . -f 1);\
    echo Altidutes range: $$zMin $$zMax;\
    python ../script/slice.py $$zMin $$zMax $(SLICES) > ./slices.tmp.txt
```

Then  `$$zMin` and `$$zMax` are defined in the python command, which therefor receives its needed values and it works.

#### Comment and question

This seems very ugly to me. **How should I do to properly pass values to the last python command within my makefile ?**

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question.  What's ugly about it?  One extra ;\ ?

Comment: @MadScientist: the answer and explanation you deleted was valuable. I assume I should be able to store the variable, then to call and reuse it in the last line.

Comment: Maybe but you already knew it because you already provided that solution in your "Hack" section of the question.  So I deleted my answer. I still don't quite understand what the issue is.  You _are_ storing the value in (shell) variables then using them in the last line...??

Comment: I never did such inlining of several command in any `make` tasks before. It just seems counter intuitive to me. But thank you for the answer, it's actually your answer which pointed me toward "my" hack.